# images and kernels of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let's say we have two matrices $A$ and $B$. 
Now I have two problems:

**$1.$** if $R(A)=R(B)$ then $N(A)=N(B)$

**$2.$** if $R(A)=R(B)$ and $N(A)=N(B)$ then $A=B$

Where $R$ is the image of matrix and $N$ is the kernel of a matrix. I need to determine if the previous statements are true and explain why. I understand what these subspaces are contained of, but I just don't know how to conclude if the statements are true or not. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried taking some examples?

Comment: @Guy yes, but the problem is that I first need to say if those are true or not, then explain why.. I am not allowed to do any calculations or anything

Comment: @ivana14 If you find a counter-example, then it is false. So you can do some calculations first to see if you can find any counter-examples.

Comment: Are there any requirements on $A$ and $B$ other than being matrices (i.e. dimension requirements)?

Comment: @ivana14 OK, but you can still use these examples to get an intuition. Usually, when dealing with such questions, it is good to first check some examples, and then try to prove / disprove

Comment: @Aweygan no, there are no other requirements, so I just assume that $A$ and $B$ can be any dimension matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(1)$, consider

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix},
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

For $(2)$ consider the same $A$ and

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: okay, in $(1)$ the two matrices have the same image and kernels, if I am right. But how can I know if that goes for any two matrices which have the same images? And in $(2)$ those two matrices have the same ranges and kernels but are actually not equal.. So I guess I can say that the second statement is actually wrong, since it cannot be applied to any two matrices

Comment: In $(1)$, the ranges are the same, but the kernels are different.

Comment: aren't the ranges of $A$ and $B$ in $(2)$ different? For $A$ it's vector $(1, 0)$ and for $B$ it's $(2, 0)$..

Comment: No, both have range spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$